# How to render Bitmap[] to Canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, canvas, bitmap

I may get an array or list of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and I want to render them to a canvas(may one piece per second). How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: depends on your platform. (silverlight,wpf,winforms,asp.net, etc.)